# Transforming rows in a PCA context using dudi.pca

Tags: r, pca

I have a huge matrix of genetic data (1e7 rows representing individuals x 5,000 columns representing markers) on which I would like to perform a PCA in order to keep c. 20 columns. However, due to memory issues, I cannot perform PCA using either dudi.pca or big.PCA on R 3.1.2 on a 8GB 64bits machine.

An alternative was to compute an approximation of the coordinates of principal axes on a row-subset of the matrix and then transform the whole matrix using a linear combination with the approximate PA coordinates.

I am facing a simple PCA-related problem using dudi.pca: how can I get the row coordinates using the original matrix and the matrix of column coordinates (= principal axes) ?

Here is a simple example, let's take a random matrix M (3 rows and 4 columns) such as:

```
 M= 
1 9 10 13
20 13 20 7
18 19 17 10
```

Doing dudi.pca(M, center=T, scale=T) and keeping only one PC, dudi.pca outputs the following $c1 matrix (column normed scores ie principal axes):

```
c1 =
-0.547
-0.395
-0.539
0.504
```

To compute the row coordinates of the data on the first principal axis, I thought doing the inner product:

```
r =
-0.547*1 + -0.395*9 + -0.539*10 + -0.504*13
-0.547*20 + -0.395*13 + -0.539*20 + -0.504*17
-0.547*18 + -0.395*19 + -0.539*17 + -0.504*10
```

i.e.

```
r =
-2.944
-23.331
-21.481
```

But if I look up at the $li (row coordinates ie principal components) natively computed by dudi.pca on the same dataset, I read:

```
r' =
2.565
-1.559
-1.005
```

Am I doing something wrong when formulating the row coordinates using dudi.pca $ci matrix?

Many thanks for your help,

Quaerens.

Code :

```
> M=matrix(c(1,9,10,13,20,13,20,7,18,19,17,10), ncol=4, byrow=T)
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    9   10   13
[2,]   20   13   20    7
[3,]   18   19   17   10
> N=dudi.pca(M, center=T, scale=T, scannf=F, nf=1)
> N$c1
          CS1
V1 -0.5468634
V2 -0.3955638
V3 -0.5389504
V4  0.5039863
> r=c( M[1,] %*% N$c1[,1], M[2,] %*% N$c1[,1], M[3,] %*% N$c1[,1] )
> r
[1]  -2.94462 -23.33070 -21.48155
> N$li
      Axis1
1  2.565165
2 -1.559546
3 -1.005619
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is still of interest...

ADE4 works on the duality diagram, hence when p is greater than n singular value decomposition is carried out on the nxn symmetric matrix

```
library(ade4)
M=matrix(c(1,9,10,13,20,13,20,7,18,19,17,10), ncol=4, byrow=T)
M
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    9   10   13
## [2,]   20   13   20    7
## [3,]   18   19   17   10
N=dudi.pca(M, center=T, scale=T, scannf=F, nf=1)

#dimensions of M
n=3
p=4

X=scalewt(M,center=T,scale=T)

#this could be done in two ways. Singular Value Decomposition or Duality    Diagrams.
#Consider a Singular value decomposition of X; S=UDV; where S is X, U is the left triangular matrix, and V is the right triangular matrix, and D is the diagonal matrix of eigen values

svd=svd(X)

#These are equivalent
N$c1
svd$v[,1]

#Equivalent
N$eig
## [1] 3.341175 0.658825
svd$d[1:2]
## [1] 3.341175 0.658825

#Diagonal matrix of eigen values
lambda=diag(svd$d)

#N$lw gives the row weights
N$lw
#0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333

#find the inverse of the diagonal matrix of row weights; this is the normalization part
K=solve(sqrt(diag(N$lw,n)))%*%svd$u


#These are equivalent
head(K[,1])
## [1]  1.4033490 -0.8531958 -0.5501532
head(N$l1)
##          RS1
## 1  1.4033490
## 2 -0.8531958
## 3 -0.5501532

#Find Principal Components
pc=K%*%sqrt(lambda)
#These are equivalent

head(pc)
##           [,1]       [,2]
## [1,]  2.565165 -0.1420130
## [2,] -1.559546 -0.9154578
## [3,] -1.005619  1.0574707
head(N$li)
##       Axis1
## 1  2.565165
## 2 -1.559546
## 3 -1.005619
```

This could also be done using the duality diagram implemented in ade4
look here for references on the duality diagram implemented in ade4: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1324399594

```
Q<-diag(p)
D<-diag(1/n, n)
rk<-qr(X)
rank=rk$rank

#Statistical Triplets
V<-t(X)%*%D%*%X 
W<-X%*%Q%*%t(X)

#Compute the eigen values and vectors of the statistical triplet
example.eigen=eigen(W%*%D)

#Equivalent
N$eig
## [1] 3.341175 0.658825
example.eigen$values[1:rank]
## [1] 3.341175 0.658825

#Diagonal matrix of eigen values
lambda=diag(example.eigen$values[1:rank])


#find the inverse of the diagonal matrix of row weights; this is the normalizing part
Binv<-solve(sqrt(D))

K=Binv%*%example.eigen$vectors[,1:rank]

#These are equivalent
head(K[,1])
## [1]  1.4033490 -0.8531958 -0.5501532
head(N$l1)
##          RS1
## 1  1.4033490
## 2 -0.8531958
## 3 -0.5501532

#Find Principal Components
pc=K%*%sqrt(lambda)
#These are equivalent

head(pc)
##           [,1]       [,2]
## [1,]  2.565165 -0.1420130
## [2,] -1.559546 -0.9154578
## [3,] -1.005619  1.0574707
head(N$li)
##       Axis1
## 1  2.565165
## 2 -1.559546
## 3 -1.005619
```